# Icon / Symbol missing in vector tile map (integrated by ArcGIS API for JavaScript)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, markers, arcgis-portal, icon

The web map was made by esri tools, since it contains two tile layers (a map tile layer overlapped by a vector tile layer) which hosting by Portal for ArcGIS 10.4, and then integrates through ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.0.

The symbol is missing in the map, whereas the label is normally displayed, such strange circumstance only appeared in my computer; that is, others' computer shows the right contents in the same html file.

How do I fix the problem?

---

Abnormal status: mark icons and the symbol behind label were missing.

[image: Unormal status: mark icons and the symbol behind label were missing.]

Normal status: mark icons and the label symbols were all appeared.

[image: Normal status: mark icons and the label symbols were all appeared.]

Comment: 1. Can you replicate with a live example you can share?   

2. Can you replicate in different browsers?    

3. Are the labels created in ArcMap and then served up to ArcGIS Server or at the WebMap level in the Map Viewer?

4. The two images look to be at different scale levels.  Do you have scale ranges applied to your label classes?  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/text/label-classes.htm